# How to specify a type guard for a function type with arguments without any in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics, contravariance

Function types are contravariant for arguments and covariant for return types. How do i specify a generic function type with argument that extends `Container` type without using `any` in this case?

```
type Container<V> = {
  id: string;
  join: (value: V) => void;
};

const process = <V extends Container<unknown>>(processFn: (container: V) => boolean) => {
  // do something with processFn
}

type ExtendedContainer = Container<number> & { status: string; };
const processFn = (container: ExtendedContainer) => {
  return true;
}

process(processFn);
```

I understand why it errors. What i don't get is how i can express such a system without resorting to `any` in `processFn` type declaration for `process`?
Or else, how can i make sure that the `container` argument extends type `Container` in general and get its type parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a somewhat convoluted and ugly solution, using conditional types, that works:

```js
function process<C>(processFn: C extends Container<infer _> ? (value: C) => boolean : never) {
  // do something with processFn
}

process(processFn);

process((a: string) => true); // Argument of type '(a: string) => true' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.(2345)
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHtx1NAPANQD5kBvAKGWWABMAuZAZzClAHMBuC5AK3VHoAUANzgAbAK4R6%20AJTIAvMSF9qnAL6cyMcSARhgmZAAco6JAwa5UhASbMQLAMRD1UyCAA9IIagzSYwbBA8UBhoZAB9YgB%20ZGExSVc5RWQAI3R0UQg4EGR6YKFoOXJKAHpS5Gp0RnQAWwgwAAs2ZAB3YCbjU3MGZzI1MjJQSFhEFABRLwgfCGoMLBwodymfP3nAxdwQcVrU6GISxkCwcQZ6JhYQDn7B7V19Qzse5wEEAKDoeknvaln1j6gxS4UAa4iguWYknUgyeDgYtm6cOcMk0sIsAgEcHOzDYyWIkIgKOQ5WQAEEoKwdtMwMh0DBkGAAJ5GFAAckx2MurDxDKgklZVD8IHQNLgFmArBAcFSWQZ1SMcCgcHqI1p9KZLOQrIK0FZADoBAAmADMABYAKwyIA)

Comment: Thank you so much, i don't think it is uglier than using `any`! Especially considering the fact that i'll definitely need the `_` type later in the function. You helped a lot :)

Comment: After trying to implement it i realized there is no way to get the type of infer in the body of the function. No types will help because you can not reliably check if the function does indeed accept the specified argument. A trade-off must be made and you gotta lie about the types for the sake of DX. The original idea was to return an extended function that would accept different arguments and a controller tied to the original arguments. It is currently impossible to do without `any`